# Why has this piece of code to be there?

Tags: python, physics, vpython, glowscript

I try to understand this code and I actually understood the whole thing except these 2 line:

```
f_grav = gravity * sun.mass * earth.mass * (sun.pos - earth.pos).norm() / (sun.pos - earth.pos).mag2
earth.vel = earth.vel + (f_grav/earth.mass) * dt
```

Why couldn't it just be: `f_grav = gravity * sun.mass * earth.mass / (sun.pos-earth.pos)**2`

I also dont get the role of `.norm()` and `.mag2`

Here is the whole code snippet of the program(GlowScript):

```
sunRadius = 10 * realSunRadius   # the size for our solar system
earthRadius = sunRadius * 0.25    # note: real value would be sunRadius * 0.01, a good choice for sim is * 0.25
astronomicalUnit = 212.7 * realSunRadius     # the distance from Sun to Earth - the Sun is about 100 Sun diameters away      
gravity = 6.6e-11   # sets the strength of the gravitational constant to 6.6x10-11 Newton x meters squared per kilograms squared

# create the Sun object
sun = sphere( radius = sunRadius, opacity = 0.7, emissive = True, texture = "http://i.imgur.com/yoEzbtg.jpg" ) 
sun.mass = 2e30   # mass of the Sun in kilograms is 2,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 kg
sun.pos = vec(0,0,0)
sun.vel = vec(0,0,0)

# place a few sources of light at the same position as the Sun to illuminate the Earth and Moon objects
sunlight = local_light( pos = vec(0,0,0), color=color.white )
more_sunlight = local_light( pos = vec(0,0,0), color=color.white )  # I found adding two lights was about right

# create the Earth object
earth = sphere ( radius = earthRadius, texture = "http://i.imgur.com/rhFu01b.jpg",make_trail=True)
earth.mass = 6e24   # mass of Earth in kilograms
earth.pos = vec(astronomicalUnit, 0, 0)
earth.vel = vec(0,0,-30000)   # the Earth is moving around 30000 m/s


dt = 10000


# below is the main loop of the program - everything above is "setup" and now we are in the main "loop" where all the action occurs
while (True):   # this will make it loop forever

    rate(100)   # this limits the animation rate so that it won't depend on computer/browser processor speed

    # calculate the force of gravity on each object
    f_grav = gravity * sun.mass * earth.mass * (sun.pos - earth.pos).norm() / (sun.pos - earth.pos).mag2
    earth.vel = earth.vel + (f_grav/earth.mass) * dt


    # update the position of the Earth and Moon by using simple circle trigonometry
    earth.pos = earth.pos + earth.vel * dt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(sun.pos-earth.pos)` is a vector. I don't think you can do `(sun.pos-earth.pos)**2` because you can't square a vector. Unless you're trying to do a dot product of the vector with itself? But the result of a dot product is a scalar, so `f_grav` would be a scalar. Forces are vectors, so it doesn't make sense to use a dot product there.

In comparison, `f_grav = gravity * sun.mass * earth.mass * (sun.pos - earth.pos).norm() / (sun.pos - earth.pos).mag2` makes sense because you're multiplying `(sun.pos - earth.pos).norm()`, a vector, by three scalars, and dividing by one scalar. So the result is a vector as desired.

Answer (score 1):

`.norm()` returns a unit vector so that the result is a vector not a scalar. This is the vector form of Newtonian gravity. (See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation#Vector_form))

`.mag2` does the same thing as what is expected from `**2`, however in general, powers of vectors are not defined, so it wouldn't make sense to define the exponentiation operator on the vector class.

Comment: More specifically, mag2 gives you the 2-norm of a vector. The 2-norm is basically Euclidean distance, or "as the crow flies". 1-norm is the "taxicab distance" - the distance if you could only move in one dimension at a time. So the 2-norm of <1,1> is sqrt(2), and the 1-norm is <1,1> is 2.